# Integral of orthogonal functions with a differential operator

Tags: real-analysis, integration, calculus-of-variations, quantum-mechanics, variational-analysis

I have an infinite set of functions $\{q_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ which can be used to expand functions $q(\tau)$ from a given class as series, i.e.
$$
q(\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nq_n(\tau)
$$
and whose members satisfy the following orthogonality condition:
$$
\int\limits_0^{\hbar\beta} q_n(\tau)q_m(\tau)d\tau=\delta_{nm}.
$$
I need to evaluate the following integral
$$
I=\int\limits_0^{\hbar\beta}d\tau'c_nq_n(\tau')c_mq_m(\tau')\left[-M\frac{d^2}{d\tau'^2}+V''(q_c)\right],
$$
and I don't know how to use the orthogonality condition in order to do the calculations. How could I proceed?

**Edit: explanation of the origin of the problem**

This integral comes from the expansion of the euclidean action around a certain path
$$
S[q(\tau)]\simeq S[q_c(\tau)]+\int_0^{\hbar\beta}\int_0^{\hbar\beta} d\tau'd\tau''\delta q(\tau')\delta q(\tau'')\left.\frac{\delta^2S}{\delta q(\tau')\delta q(\tau'')}\right|_{q_c},
$$
where
$$
\left.\frac{\delta^2S}{\delta q(\tau')\delta q(\tau'')}\right|_{q_c}=\left[-M\frac{d^2}{d\tau'^2}\delta(\tau'-\tau'')+V''(q_c)\delta(\tau'-\tau'')\right],
$$
and the variations can be expanded in this type of orthongonal functions, i.e. as
$$
q(\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nq_n(\tau).
$$
Thank you very much.

Comment: The operator should be to the left. Are the functions eigenfunctions of the operator?

Comment: This requires more context before it can be answered in general. What operator are you applying? What basis of functions do you have in mind?